# How to send the mail from c#

Tags: c#, email, send

I have code,

```
 System.Web.Mail.MailMessage oMailMessage = new MailMessage();
            oMailMessage.From = strFromEmaild;
            oMailMessage.To = strToEmailId;
            oMailMessage.Subject = strSubject;
            oMailMessage.Body = strBody;
            SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
            SmtpMail.Send(oMailMessage);
```

(all variables have values)

I have installed SMTP virtual services. why it is unable to send emails. why it is not working ??

**EDIT**

```
public bool SendMail(string strToEmailId, string strFromEmaild, string strSubject, string strBody)
{
    try
    {
        System.Web.Mail.MailMessage oMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        oMailMessage.From = strFromEmaild;
        oMailMessage.To = strToEmailId;
        oMailMessage.Subject = strSubject;
        oMailMessage.Body = strBody;
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "SERVERNAME";
        SmtpMail.Send(oMailMessage);

        return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

I have this code. It is executing fine and is returning true, but I'm not getting any email in the inbox.

## What else could be wrong?

### Getting some mails in BadMail Dir at C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Badmail also in Queue Directory getting some mails here ... what does that means..??

I found that mail only can sent to gmail accounts... why it is?

Comment: COuld be firewall/antivirus blocking it, from your machine, or the server, or both. What happens if you configure outlook with the same parameters?

Comment: I don't think "localhost" is the name of your smtp server

Comment: Are there any firewall restrictions etc in ur network etc?

Comment: Does this code run without any exceptions, or does it run without the recipient getting the email?

Comment: strFromEmaild should be strFromEmailId?

Comment: is it going to a junk mail folder?

Comment: Try changing SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "SERVERNAME"; to SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";

Comment: This might help: http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/4.4.7.aspx

Comment: As I said in my post, there is usually a description in those files within the badmail and queue folders that tells you why they weren't sent. Maybe post what you find and we can help you more accurately..

Comment: hello Lalit, did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine what the error is:

```
try
{
 SmtpMail.Send(oMailMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//breakpoint here to determine what the error is:
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

From here, please edit your question with that exception details.

Comment: No...If i get erroor or exception then that will catch before .. see my another post . I have given total coded function of mine.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, your code is fine and is most likely something in your SMTP configuration or maybe your email client your sending your test emails to is marking them as spam. If it's spam, well that's easy enoughto figure out. 
If it's something with the email, you can go to your mailroot folder and their will be some folders there with the email files along with a description. See if there's anything in the BadMail folder or the queue folder and open them up in notepad and view what error is given for why they weren't sent.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell, but one possibility is that you haven't enabled anonymous access on the SMTP virtual server. Go to the the virtual server properties dialog, select the Access tab, click the Access Control button, and make sure that Anonymous Access is enabled.

Comment: i HAVE CHECKED IT, IT IS ANNONYMOUS ENABLED

Comment: @Lalit, why are you so mad? No caps please.

Comment: sorry nathann.. really i m mad dude

Comment: You could try installing an email client and configuring it to use the virtual smtp server. Can you successfully send email using that?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything functionally wrong with your program.  It's likely a configuration issue between your program and the mail server.  I would try the following to diagnose the problem.

1. Wrap the code in a try/catch block and see if the exception message contains useful data
2. Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost just to rule out anything crazy
3. Ensure your SMTP server is running on the standard port (25 I believe)

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can follow the following code:

```
try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your gmail id", "password");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(textBoxTo.Text);
            msg.From = new MailAddress("your gmail id");
            msg.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text;
            msg.Body = textBoxMsg.Text;
            Attachment data = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment.Text);
            msg.Attachments.Add(data);
            client.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Sent Message.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried 127.0.0.1 instead of Localhost? 
Also have you tested that the SMTP service is working, check out this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual smtp server Add relay restrictions and connection control so that none of the outside connections are allowed

[image]