# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' in my Code

Tags: c#

I was trying to send email to multiple email address which was in my database .My code is given below

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ArrayList list_emails = new ArrayList();
        int i=0,email = 0;


        String condata = "data source =(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE))); user id = myuser; password = myuser";
        String qry = "select emailid from emailmachin";
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(condata);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(qry, con);
        OracleDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {


                email = myReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                list_emails.Add(email); //Add email to a arraylist
                i = i + 1 - 1; //increment or ++i
                //string emailIdc = myReader["emailid"].ToString();
                //textBoxTo.Text = emailIdc;
                myReader.Close();
                con.Close();
                foreach (string email_to in list_emails)
                {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(email_to);
                    mail.Subject = "Welcome to C#";
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(hold_Account);
                    mail.Body = "Test";
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SMTP Server");
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

}
```

in this Line of code `email = myReader.GetValue(i).ToString();` there show the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: I wonder why you defined `email` to be of type `int` then?

Comment: What do *you* think `i = i + 1 - 1;` does? Hint: It doesn't increment anything.

Comment: That's my another mistake. Thanks a lot :) .

Answer (score 2):

`myReader.GetValue(i).ToString()` does not return an integer, it returns a string, because of this, you need to define `email` as a `string`.

```
int i = 0;
string email = string.Empty;
```

This might have been a mistake because of all of the different mail variables, try using better variable names.

Also, your code does not increment `i` properly, it leaves it unchanged. Try simply `i++;` instead of `i = i + 1 - 1;`

Answer (score -2):

1. when you don't know to declare your variable with string, int, char, etc, don't worry, just type "var" and allow C# to choose it's type, my friend :)
2. in C# a string cannot implicitly convert to int and you should explicitly do this with this function: `Convert.ToInt32(your string variable or your string with quotation mark);`
3. when you want to send an Email to multiple recipients, I think it's better that you use "BCC"(Blind carbon copy) instead of "TO", because `smtp.Send(mail);` only runs one time
4. check it out [How to send the mail from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118413/how-to-send-the-mail-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Advising to use var when not understanding typing hardly seems good advice :)

Comment: but at first it's better than to have something that can be run, then in review, testing and other part of programming section we optimize our code, anyway it's my opinion dude, think agile ;)

Comment: How does changing `int i=0,email = 0;` to `var i=0,email = 0;` (that's what you're suggesting, right?) help anything? That doesn't remove an error, it *adds* one.

Comment: nope dear svick, without initializing is true :). I use this type several times, and in my VS it's work, maybe in yours it doesn't work ;), and for this reason I tried to help, so plz read whole answer and leave a comment, anyways, thanks a lot to read my first paragraph :)

Comment: @Reza.Ace I'm not saying saying you should use `var`, I use it all the time too. But saying “if you don't know, try `var`” is a terrible advice.